# Based on PANS-OPS, what is the earliest turning point that can be used in a missed approach?

Tags: missed-approach, procedure-design, pans-ops

I am studying ICAO's PANS-OPS 8168 manual, and I have noticed conflicting guidelines regarding the permitted earliest turning point during a missed approach.

In section 6.2.1.1, it clearly states:

> *6.2 Climb Gradient and MOC. 6.2.1 Initial Phase. 6.2.11*. The initial phase begins at the earliest missed approach point (MAPt) and ends at the start of climb point
>   (SOC). The manoeuvre during this phase requires the concentrated attention of the pilot, especially when establishing
>   the climb and the changes in configuration, and it is assumed that guidance equipment is not utilized during these
>   manoeuvres. **No turns may be specified during this phase**.

A few pages later, it also states:

> 6.4.7 *Turn Specified at the MAPt*. Where the turn is specified at the MAPt, which means that the pilot is supposed to establish the aeroplane on a climbing
>   path and then to turn, the OCA/H will be taken as the turn altitude/height and the turn initiation area will extend from
>   the earliest MAPt to the SOC (see *Figures I-4-6-10* and *I-4-6-20*).

However, in Figure I-4-6-10, a turn less than 15 degrees is depicted to begin **immediately at MAPt**, rather than at SOC. On the other hand, turns more than 15 degrees seem to begin at SOC as it is intended (Figure I-4-6-20).

[image]

[image]

Additionally, in section 6.4.5 (Turn initiated at a designated altitude height), it states:

> *6.4.5.2.1.1* The point where the designated altitude/height is reached is not fixed. It depends on the climb
>   performance of the aircraft and the point from which the missed approach is initiated. The aircraft may reach the
>   designated turn altitude/height:
>
> a) **as early as the earliest MAPt** when the procedure prohibits turning before the MAPt **or as early as the earliest
>   FAF** when no restrictions are provided
>
> b) after a climb using the minimum required gradient from the SOC to the point where it reaches the specified
>   altitude height. This point is called the Turn Point (TP).

In Figure I-4-6-11, one of the potential turning points is depicted near the MAPt, well before SOC.

[image]

All things considered, I can not figure out the earliest point where turning is allowed to be initiated, during a missed approach.

Could someone help me clarify this?

Comment: I would simplify it and not turn before the MAP point.

Answer (score 1):

> I can not figure out the earliest point where turning is allowed to be initiated, during a missed approach.

It is up to the designer. Nothing in PANS-OPS prohibits turns before MAPt but in that case an additional area extending from the earliest FAF needs to be protected as shown in figure I-4-6-14 PANS-OPS Vol. II.

Because early turns are not always feasible, advisable or convenient, we often disallow turns before MAPt, in which case a note to the effect will be added on the profile view of the approach chart. Any turns >15° will then be executed in the final missed approach area (Vol. II I-4-6-10 6.4.6.3.1).